# Prove linear map is projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V \to V$ be a projection onto subspace $W \le V$ along $U \le V$ where $\dim W=k$, $\dim U=l$ and also $\dim V=k+l=n$.

Prove that $f^*: V^* \to V^*$ is a projection.

I know $V^*=L(V,K)$ and $V=W \oplus U$ from assumption but I don't know how to prove linear maps is a projection

Comment: You need to know the definition of *projection* to proceed.  Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x\in V^*$ and $y\in V$.

$$((f^*)^2(x),y)=(f^*x,f^*y)=(x,f^2y)=(x,fy)=(f^*x,y)$$

where $(x,y)$ denotes $x(y)$ for $x\in V^*$ and $y\in V$.

This shows $(f^*)^2=f^*$.

---

An element of $V^*$ is a linear functional on $V$. This means that it can be evaluated in elements of $V$ and returns a scalar from $K$. Therefore if $x\in V^*$  and $y\in V$ we can evaluate $x(y)\in K$.

The definition of $f^*:V\to V^*$ is that $f^*(x)\in V^*$, for $x\in V^*$ is such that $$f^*(x)(y):=x(f(y)).$$

If we use the notation $(x,y):=x(y)$, for $x\in V^*$ and $y\in V$ then the equation above looks like $$(f^*x,y)=(x,fy)$$ which is nicer looking and similar looking to an scalar product.

Comment: I'm not comprehending how works yours steps, could you explain ? and what you mean by x(y) ?